# favicon icons not found , django website with bootstrap at front

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

My website favicon icons are no longer found. It is a simple Django website with bootstrap. It was working a few minutes ago, I tried changing the whole boot strap code.

The log i am getting when the django server is running and I use the users profile:

Not Found: /favicon.ico
[06/Feb/2021 08:53:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4502
Session data corrupted

This is were the bootstrap static is coming though in the page:

```
    {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    
    href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers look for the existence of an file called favicon.ico at the root path of your website domain, this controls the icon for the website you can see in your bookmarks folder or the address bar of your browser.

If you don't have one, then it's valid that it would return a Not Found error.

When you deploy to something like Apache, you will have to alias your favicon in a config file. However, while running Django in development mode, the following works

urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns=[
    ...

    path('favicon.ico',RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico')),
]
```

Comment: welcome man. mark this answer as correct one